# What makes Cooper pairs of electrons so fit for an unhindered current through a superconducting wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

When a superconducted wire is cooled close to 0K, the electrons could form a Cooper pair. They become (or behave) like bosons.

But what is meant that those electrons got the same, by which the Pauli-principle isn't an obstacle anymore?

And why should this Cooper pair have no resistance going through the wire anymore? Does it has lost his charge?

Comment: The idea that the constituents lose their charge comes close. I would rather say that the charges become ill-defined: the electrons (negative charge) are in a superposition with holes (positive charge). Any internal electromagnetic field would instantaneously decohere ('collapse') such a superposition, so a superconductor can only exist if it screens all electromagnetic fields. In other words $E_\textrm{internal} = 0$, which means that resistivity is zero. (Note that this reasoning also explains the Meissner effect, i.e. $B_\textrm{internal} = 0$.)

Comment: A short and sloppy answer. Assume any photons are effectively massive inside the superconductor, (through symmetry breaking), also assume that as one electron gets held back in the metal lattice, the other one of the pair gets pulled forward. They do not posses enough energy to produce retarding photons, so they meet no resistance. This is a terribly distorted picture of what is a complex effect, sorry, but I think it's the basic idea.

Comment: @CountTo10, in this question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290086/acceleration-of-electrons-from-cooper-pairs-and-em-radiation I used your comment. Perhaps you are interested in answering the question?