# Acceleration of electrons from Cooper pairs and EM radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, superconductivity

For the question [What makes Cooper pairs of electrons so fit for an unhindered current through a superconducting wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284168/what-makes-cooper-pairs-of-electrons-so-fit-for-an-unhindered-current-through-a) where was a nice comment from CountTo10:

> Assume any photons are effectively massive inside the superconductor, (through symmetry breaking), also **assume that as one electron gets held back in the metal lattice, the other one of the pair gets pulled forward**. They do not posses enough energy to produce retarding photons, so they meet no resistance.

Not getting response to this question of mine [Why don't superconducting coils radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290005/why-dont-superconducting-coils-radiate?noredirect=1#comment651436_290005) I'm asking this in an other way:

It is common sense that in a superconducting coil an electric current is flowing. Since the involved electrons are moving in circles they are subject to an acceleration. Do this electrons emit EM radiation?